# Postgres greatest-n-per-group is slow

Tags: postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

the following query find greatest value per day and it is executed to slow. How to make it faster?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Execution plans should be shared as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) as well and ideally the result of running `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`

Comment: What is the type of audit_days?

Comment: audit_days is timestamp